How to customize the filename of a download file?
Today, I downloaded Node.js. I noticed that the download button is a <a> element which link to https://nodejs.org/dist/v20.12.1/node-v20.12.1.pkg. But when I check out the response, I didn't find the Content-Disposition header. I am curious about How the response customize the filename without Content-Disposition header. Here's the response headers.


From the Content-Disposition docs, we know:

Note: Chrome, and Firefox 82 and later, prioritize the HTML <a> element's download attribute over the Content-Disposition: inline parameter (for same-origin URLs). Earlier Firefox versions prioritize the header and will display the content inline.

And,
See download attribute of the <a/> element:

Without a value, the browser will suggest a filename/extension, generated from various sources:



The Content-Disposition HTTP header
The final segment in the URL path


Let's see the <a/> element on the Node.js official site
<a href="https://nodejs.org/dist/v22.11.0/node-v22.11.0.tar.gz" role="button">...</a>

There is no download attribute and Content-Disposition HTTP header, use the final segment in the URL path which is node-v22.11.0.tar.gz
That's why the filename is node-v22.11.0.tar.gz
